# Pasar hash del modelo al controlador

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo una lista en el modelo que básicamente  debe decidir si un registro cumple una función sumar 1 a bueno de lo contrario sumar 1 a malo y que esos dos parámetros los retorne al controlador como un hash.

Lo que no se es como hacer para que el controlador reciba el resultado.

**En el controlador**

```
class GruposController < ApplicationController
  @grupos = Grupo.all
  Contacto.decidir(contador)
  Puts contador.inspect #=> me trae nil, cuando quiero que me traiga el total de buenos y malos 
  …
end
```

**En el modelo**

```
class Contacto < ApplicationRecord
  def self.decidir(contador)
  contador = Hash.new
  contador[:buenos] = 0
  contador[:malos] = 0
  @grupos.each do |grupo|
  if grupo.nombre
    contador[:buenos] += 1
  else 
    contador[:malos] += 1
  end
end
```

**ACTUALIZADO**

**Controlador:**

```
  def index
    @grupos = Grupo.all
    Contacto.decidir(@grupos)
    puts '................'
    puts params[:contador].inspect #=> me trae nil, cuando quiero que me traiga el total de buenos y malos 
    puts '................'
   end
```

**modelo:**

```
  def self.decidir(grupos)
    puts 'dentro'
    { buenos: 0, malos: 0 }.tap do |contador|
      grupos.each do |grupo|
        contador[grupo.nombre ? :buenos : :malos] += 1
        puts grupo.nombre
      end
    end
  end
```

salida del log:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-20 10:36:33 -0400
Processing by EntradaController#indice as HTML
  Rendering entrada/indice.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered entrada/indice.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 526ms (Views: 484.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/grupos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-20 10:36:36 -0400
Processing by GruposController#index as HTML
dentro
  Grupo Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "grupos".* FROM "grupos"
casa
trabajo
deporte
playa
................
nil
................
  Rendering grupos/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered grupos/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 450ms (Views: 410.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

**app en github:**
https://github.com/rrg1459/ContactosYGrupos.git

Comment: Pero en `puts params[:contador]` estás imprimiendo los parámetros, no lo que retorna `Contacto.decidir(@grupos)`.

Comment: Y como puedo imprimir lo que retorna, como se cual es la variable que tiene el contenido que necesito?

Comment: Tendrías que asignar lo que retorna el método en una variable, algo como `contador = Contacto.decidir(@grupos)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta retornar el contador, para lo cual la última línea debería ser `contador`

```
  def self.decidir(contador)
    contador = Hash.new
    contador[:buenos] = 0
    contador[:malos] = 0
    @grupos.each do |grupo|
      if grupo.nombre
        contador[:buenos] += 1
      else 
        contador[:malos] += 1
      end
    end
    contador # ésta es la que te falta
  end
```

Y solo como sugerencia, podrías hacer los siguientes cambios:

```
  # sin `(contador)` como parámetro, ya que al hacer `contador = Hash.new` 
  # simplemente estás reemplazando el valor del parámetro `contador`
  def self.decidir
    # Al hacer { buenos: 0, malos: 0 } es lo mismo que las primeras 3 líneas
    # de tu código, solo que en una única línea. Luego `.tap`, 
    # te permite modificar el objeto que lo invoca y a la vez retornarlo, 
    # sin necesidad de llamar a la variable contador al final. 
    # Más info en https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-tap
    { buenos: 0, malos: 0 }.tap do |contador|
      @grupos.each do |grupo|
        # Ya que en tanto en el if como en else realizas la misma acción, 
        # pero con distinto símbolo, puedes usar un operador ternario para 
        # realizar la acción en una única línea
        contador[grupo.nombre ? :buenos : :malos] += 1
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, pero igual me llega como valor nil, si quito el parametro del modelo dice que se mandan dos  y se espera 1.  "wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)"

por otro lado creo que
el problema lo tengo en el controlador, una actualizacion de mi controlador es:

class GruposController < ApplicationController
  @grupos = Grupo.all
  Contacto.decidir( params[:contador])
  Puts  params[:contador].inspect #=> me trae nil, cuando quiero que me traiga el total de buenos y malos 
  …
end

Comment: y se me habia olvidado, si le agregue la linea final como me indicas

Comment: @rrg1459 mejor agrega tanto el error (completo) como el controlador actualizado en tu pregunta, ya que se entiende mucho mejor que en un comentario. Si estás quitando un parámetro desde la definición del método, también debes quitar en los lugares donde se invoque a dicho método.